# Cannot find type 'SFSafariExtensionHandler' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, safari-extension, safari-app-extension

I am creating a Safari App Extension. I downloaded the Sea Creator [example project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/adopting_new_safari_web_extension_apis).

I want to send messages between the extension and javascript. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/passing_messages_between_safari_app_extensions_and_injected_scripts) provided by Apple I should be able to do it with the following function:

```swift
override func messageReceived(withName messageName: String, from page: SFSafariPage, userInfo: [String : AnyObject]!) {
    page.dispatchMessageToScript(withName: "simpleMessage", userInfo: nil)
    page.dispatchMessageToScript(withName: "complexMessage", userInfo: ["myKey": "myValue"])
}
```

In the Sea Creator project I modified the SafariWebExtensionHandler to

```swift
import SafariServices

class SafariWebExtensionHandler: SFSafariExtensionHandler {
  override func messageReceived(withName messageName: String, from page: SFSafariPage, userInfo: [String : AnyObject]!) {
    page.dispatchMessageToScript(withName: "simpleMessage", userInfo: nil)
    page.dispatchMessageToScript(withName: "complexMessage", userInfo: ["myKey": "myValue"])
  }
}
```

But I am getting a buildtime error: Cannot find type 'SFSafariExtensionHandler' in scope

I am running Xcode 13.0 beta (13A5154h) on Mac OS version 11.4

What I find weird is that I downloaded a random project from github and it doesn't throw me the same error. I am wondering if there is some additional configuration I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `SFSafariExtensionHandler` to `SFSafariExtensionHandling`

Comment: Then I get an error saying "Cannot find type 'SFSafariExtensionHandling' in scope"